# How to migrate from wooCommerce to osCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, oscommerce

Is there anyway we can migrate users and orders from wooCommerce to osCommerce? I tried finding any plugin or tools on google but no luck.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Recommendations are off-topic here, but it seems like asking osCommerce directly would be your best bet.

Comment: I googled it too, and wild result appeared: http://www.shopping-cart-migration.com/shopping-cart-migration-options/6679-woocommerce-to-oscommerce-migration

Comment: I strongly recommend you use this [WooCommerce to OsCommerce migration service](https://next-cart.com/product/woocommerce-to-oscommerce/). They will take care of your migration from A to Z, you just need to choose your plan.